# How to get only child terms of current post type?

Tags: php, wordpress

Having a custom post type 'pubs' with custom taxonomy 'types' in which admin enter parent terms and their child terms.
Using this code to get all the terms of current post type:

```
$object_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'types', array('fields' => 'all'));
    if ($object_terms) {
        echo '' . '' . '' ;
        $res = '';
        foreach ($object_terms as $term) {
            $res .=  $term->name . ',';
        }
        echo rtrim($res,' ,').'' . '';
    }
```

this code displays both parent & child terms.
Is there any way to exclude parent terms from the result? I need the code to display only child terms related to the current post.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I think if you put the following inside your foreach loop at the very top, you'll get only the children:

```
if ($term->parent == 0) continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for someone still looking:

Solution is for when you have multiple level of hierarchy and you want just last level.

```
$term_array = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
foreach ($term_array as $term_id){
    $children=get_term_children($term_id, $taxonomy);
    if(empty($children)){
        $exclude=$term_id;
    }
}
```